# Confusion in the definition of 'first passage time' (Markov Chains)

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider a state $i$ from some state space $A$. *First passage time* to state $i$ is the random variable $T_i$ defined by

$T_i(\omega) = inf$ { $n \geq 1: X_n(\omega) = i$ }.

Does this means that first passage time is the minimum number of steps required by a random variable $X_n$ to attain the value $i$ or something else?

Comment: When the time is discrete, works for me to see the markov chain as a infinity vector such that the $n$th coordinate indicates which state the process was at time $n$. In this context, $T_i$ is the first coordinate (time) you see the state $i$ in this vector. Was I clear?

Comment: Yes thanks, but it would be more clear if you can give me some example.